# cannot print values - using PHP

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to print date values before form submission but it did not print anything and submitted the form, below is my code

```
function webforms_save_submission_alter(&$fields, $context) 
{
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, ["Date_Prototype__c", "Date_Production__c", "NBIOT_Date_of_Field_Trial__c", "NBIOT_Date_Lab_Trial__c"])){
            $fields[$key] = trim($value);
            print_r($fields); // printing here
            if ($fields[$key] == 'Date_Production__c') {
                $fields[$key] = format_date(strtotime($fields['Date_Production__c']), 'medium', 'm-d-Y');
                print_r($fields); // printing here
                die;
            }
```

I want to see the date reactions before submitting the form but why it did not print anythign? can someone please help me on this?
Your help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Your question  is not really clear!

Comment: I just want to echo/print_r as you can see I have wrote print_r($fields) but it does not show anything I want to print/echo fields values?

Comment: I am guessing you are using a framework. Would be useful to know which one

Comment: I am using drupal 7 and I want to print out values before form submission and It did not print anything and submit the form

Comment: Did you check the "page source"? Maybe you are outputting this before the `<body>` and it just does not show on the page

Comment: Out of interest try `echo $fields[$key];` Or even `print_r($fields, true);`

Comment: echo or print_r ?

Comment: what should i try should i go with print_r ?

Comment: Try both and see if either work? Call it a learning exercise

Comment: both are not working? is there any other way in drupal 7 to do that.

Comment: Put more `die` statements in, before and after every condition, with different text in each to see if your code is actually running, and if so, if your conditions are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with that code, which I suspect you've only written to debug a problem? It's much too complicated for that. Also, die is a function, and needs to be called with parentheses; Syntax errors are also a likely reason for why your code did nothing. Check your watchdog logs.

Try this code instead:

```
function webforms_save_submission_alter(&$fields, $context) 
{
    var_dump($fields);
    die();
}
```